# How would you translate "skim coat"?

Tags: traduction

I'm trying to do some building work on my house.

I've asked a [question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/117669/23505) and the gent came up with `skimcoat with drywall compound`.

I did some search on the Internet for some decent translation but I could not find any.

Any help is more than welcome.

Comment: You mean you are doing work ***on your house or home***. Work at home means you work on a computer or stuff envelopes or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the noun [**enduit**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/enduit) is a good translation for *skim coat*:

> 1. CONSTR. Fin revêtement appliqué sur les parements d'une construction, afin de les protéger, de leur donner une meilleure apparence. Enduit de mortier, de plâtre; enduit tyrolien.